# Is it legal to publicly share questionnaires from research articles?

Tags: research-process, copyright, policy

I've found articles on the development of diagnostic questionnaires that I only have access to through my university. I'm interested in sharing some of them publicly online so more people can have access to these materials, likely on my personal website.

Would it be legal to share these survey instruments as long as I cite them properly? If not, would it be legal for me to reference their questions outside of the context of a survey (so no measurement or scoring) with a citation?

I live in Canada, if relevant.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you want to share questionnaires or articles about them?

Comment: You should check the source for copyright. Some such things are _very_ closely held. Some diagnostics become meaningless if widely known.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be legal to share these survey instruments as long as I cite them properly?

You cannot legally share documents without permission in many jurisdictions, regardless of whether you reference the original source.

> If not, would it be legal for me to reference their questions outside
>   of the context of a survey (so no measurement or scoring) with a
>   citation?

You can probably cite the document (assuming the document's existence isn't confidential), but (in many jurisdictions) you can only quote the question if you have permission to do so, given that the document isn't public.

**Ask your institute for guidance.**